# What the PhantomReference class is intended for besides its usage in the Cleaner class?

Tags: java

Could someone explain what the `PhantomReference` class is intended for besides its usage in the `Cleaner` class? Th `PhantomReference` class was introduced at December 1998 in Java 1.2 by Mark Reinhold and it's not clear what was the intention of the author. About 19 years later, at September 2017 in Java 9 the `finalize()` method was deprecated and marked for removal but it isn't removed even in Java 22. As an alternative to that deprecated method the `Cleaner` class was added, that uses the `PhantomReference` class internally to free resources without using a reference to the garbage collected object that holds them. Using the `PhantomReference` class directly (especially before the `Cleaner` class was introduced) seems to be over complicated. And considering that even the `finalize()` method is rarely used even in code for Java older than Java 9 the `PhantomReference` class seems to be practically never used before Java 9. I can't imagine anyone writing something like the following homemade analogue of the `Cleaner` class instead of implementing just the `finalize()` method before Java 9. Why the `PhantomReference` class isn't internal? Who needs it and for what purpose?

```java
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.util.*;

class ModernFinalizingObject {
    private static final ReferenceQueue<ModernFinalizingObject> referenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    private static final Set<FinalizingPhantomReference> phantomSet = new HashSet<>();

    protected final Collection<AutoCloseable> resources = new LinkedList<>();

    {
        phantomSet.add(new FinalizingPhantomReference(this, referenceQueue, resources));
    }

    static {
        var th = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    var phantomRef = (FinalizingPhantomReference) referenceQueue.remove();
                    phantomRef.modernFinalize();
                    phantomSet.remove(phantomRef);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("someone is cheating", e);
                }
            }
        });
        th.setDaemon(true); // don't block shutting down
        th.start();
    }

    protected <T extends AutoCloseable> T meetResource(T resource) {
        resources.add(resource);
        return resource;
    }
}

class FinalizingPhantomReference extends PhantomReference<ModernFinalizingObject> {
    private final Collection<AutoCloseable> resources;

    public FinalizingPhantomReference(ModernFinalizingObject referent,
                                      ReferenceQueue<? super ModernFinalizingObject> referenceQueue,
                                      Collection<AutoCloseable> resources) {
        super(referent, referenceQueue);
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    public void modernFinalize() {
        resources.forEach(r -> {
            try {
                r.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
        });
    }
}

class Resource implements AutoCloseable {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Resource " + hashCode() + " is doing something");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Resource " + hashCode() + " is closed.");
    }
}

class ModernFinalizingService extends ModernFinalizingObject {
    private Resource resource1 = meetResource(new Resource());
    private Resource resource2 = meetResource(new Resource());

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Service is doing something...");
        resource1.doSomething();
        resource2.doSomething();
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ModernFinalizingService service = new ModernFinalizingService();
        service.doSomething();

        // make it ready to be collected as a garbage
        service = null;

        // advice the JVM to run Garbage Collector
        System.gc();

        // emulate the real work is continuing, giving some time to all the above finalization finishing
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see how this is answerable. We don’t have statistics on the global code base.

Comment: I expect to get an answer from someone who really used the `PhantomReference` class directly in their code or had seen such usage.

Comment: But that doesn’t tell you what ‘common usage’ is.

Comment: A few real examples of that rarely used class usages will tell me that.

Comment: No it won’t. You don’t get ‘common’ without a sufficient sample size, and you have no way of knowing that that even is.

Comment: What is the sufficient sample size in this case? Do you think the `PhantomReference` class is used in more than a dozen projects?

Comment: You can see usages on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=PhantomReference&type=code